# Run code only in production environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, production-environment

I am developing an `ASP.NET` application.

I have this sort of line in my code:

```
message.CC.Add("ALL@mycompany.com");
```

When working on development environment I would like this line not to be executed, so far, my solution is to comment it out before publishing.

Is there any built-in custom production flag in `ASP.NET` ?

Something like:

```
if (productionFlag)
    message.CC.Add("ALL@mycompany.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is enough for you to use:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // we are not in production..
}
```

But maybe not. I'm not aware of another technique for now. On the other hand I think if you use something like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="IsProduction" value="Y"/>
</appSettings>
```

in the config file can be risky because I can change it whenever I want.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are no built in flags, however you can make your own.

I would suggest that you use the web config file to allow you to configure your application for a production or test deploy

Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="IsProduction" value="Y"/>
</appSettings>
```

Code Behind:

```
bool isProduction = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsProduction"];
```